# What is the custom domain DNS entry used for in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

To [add a custom domain to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) you are required to register the Azure AD DNS with your domain registrar.  What does Azure AD actually do with this registration?  Does it serve resources out of this domain (if so what) or is the registration only used to verify your ownership of the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a TXT record, so it won't redirect traffic or anything. It is only used to prove you actually own the domain. By requiring you to enter a random piece of text in a DNS record, you show that you are able to modify DNS records for the domain.